# understanding blocks (login with twitter)

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to understand blocks in Objective-C. Take for example logging into Twitter. I want the main thread to wait until the block is finished.

How can I achieve this in the following code. The method showMain is just transitioning to the next view. The array TweetArray is empty because the async block is not finished. Right now, I'm using the method performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:. Please explain the concept of blocks in some detail.

```
    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
             if (granted)
             {
                 NSArray *accounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                 // Check if the users has setup at least one Twitter account
                 if (accounts.count > 0)
                 {
                     ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:0];

                     SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:twitterAccount.username forKey:@"screen_name"]];
                     [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                     // Making the request
                     [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                             if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                                 return;
                             }
                             if (error) {
                                 return;
                             }
                             // Check if there is some response data
                             if (responseData) {
                                 NSError *error = nil;
                                 NSArray *TweetArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                                 NSLog(@"%@", TweetArray);
                             }
                         });
                     }];
                 }
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Access denied");
             }
         });

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

             [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showMain) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
         });
     }];
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: *Please explain the concept of blocks in some detail* is ***slightly*** too broad for being answered correctly. Grab a Objective-C book, read the block chapter and come back with a narrower question.

Answer (score 1):

Explain the whole concept of blocks in just an answer is ask to much, you should read the documentation and search in some books.

But looking directly to your problem, I will try to tell what's going on:

This method `performRequestWithHandler:` from your `twitterInfoRequest` object, like the name already says, performs a requisition to twitter's servers, returning a `responseData`. This method receives as a parameter a block, which will be called exactly when the requisition arrives. So, this block is nothing but a piece of code that will be executed to `handle` the `responseData`, when you receive it.

So, if you want to do something **after** the response arrives, you must just put this inside this block. In your case, it would be the call to `showMain` method:

```
(...)
[twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                             return;
                         }
                         if (error) {
                             return;
                         }
                         // Check if there is some response data
                         if (responseData) {
                             NSError *error = nil;
                             NSArray *TweetArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                             NSLog(@"%@", TweetArray);

                             [self showMain];
                         }
                     });
                 }];
```

Ps: as you are already executing this handle block inside the main thread (with the  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...` ) you don't have to call the method through `performSelectorOnMainThread`.